# Issues with cyanogenmod 11 on galaxy y

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting

I tried to root my Galaxy Y. I installed cyanogenmod 11 on it. But the version of cyanogenmod I got had many bugs. Even the phone call is not working. How could I fix this situation. Please help

Comment: did you flash a stable version of cyanogenmod, or was it a nightly? build?

Comment: I took the rom from __http://www.galaxyyarchive.info/2014/06/cyanogenmod11-for-samsung-galaxy-y-gt.html

Comment: That's a nightly build. They often have bugs and aren't classed as stable, so that could be why the dialler didn't work. It would be worth checking with other users of the ROM to see if they have encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-flashing a suitable ROM from XDA.
[Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 ROMs [XDA]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-y#romList)

Comment: i tried this one. but my phone is not getting recognized by odin, even after installing the Samsung Kies

Comment: That's an issue with your phone drivers being not installed properly.

Comment: Yes ! It was the problem with my Samsung Kies. The issue was fixed when I re-installed the drivers. Now I have the Sock ROM in my device. Let me root it once again with ROM from the XDA you shared ;) :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information :) Now its really working. Just one more this is there a way to get a stable  cyanogenmod 11 for samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 ?

Comment: Check it here : www.cyanogenmod.org